# jQuery .data() doesn't persist in jQuery created elements

Tags: jquery, html, methods

In the following example, I've added some html elements with jQuery, then assigned some data to them (again with jQuery).  I can't figure out why `$("#p1").data();` returns an empty object after the assignment of `$("p2").data("intID", "b");`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Create a new <p> elment and use jQuery to assign some data to it
    $("body").html($("body").html() + "<p id='p1'>TestOne</p>");
    $("#p1").data("intID", "a");

    //confirm data assignment was successful
    console.log($("#p1").data());

    //Create new <p> element and assign different data to it
    $("body").html($("body").html() + "<p id='p2'>TestTwo</p>");
    $("#p2").data("intID", "b");

    //Check that all data still exists (spoiler alert: it doesn't)
    console.log($("#p1").data());
    console.log($("#p2").data());
});
```

Resulting console output:

```
{intID: "a"}
{}
{intID: "b"}
```

I've already verified that this works the way I want with pre-existing HTML elements (i.e. those defined in the HTML source). I've combed over https://api.jquery.com/data/ and can't figure it out from there.

I understand that there are other ways of doing what I want to accomplish, so I'm more interested in a theoretical explanation of why this happens than I am in an alternative solution.  I would think it's a bug, but that degree of coding hubris died in me long ago.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `.data()` and it persists the values. However, the issue is the way you're creating the `<p>` elements. Use `.append()` instead, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Create a new <p> elment and use jQuery to assign some data to it
    $("body").append("<p id='p1'>TestOne</p>");
    $("#p1").data("intID", "a");

    //confirm data assignment was successful
    console.log($("#p1").data());

    //Create new <p> element and assign different data to it
    $("body").append("<p id='p2'>TestTwo</p>");
    $("#p2").data("intID", "b");

    //Check that all data still exists (spoiler alert: it doesn't)
    console.log($("#p1").data());
    console.log($("#p2").data());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='p1'>TestOne</p>
<p id='p2'>TestTwo</p>
```

Comment: Ahh.  I'm guessing it has something to do with this line in the .html() documentation:

When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening.